# click function using multiple div not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

here I use four `div`'s when i click a first `div`, other  all `div` are getting opacity its working fine,I want when I move to other `di`v first `div` still no change to opacity

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".category-item").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass("black");
        $(".category-item").addClass("blue");
    });
});
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: You really had me going there with `opacity : unset`, I had to spend a minute looking it up in the standard, as I haven't seen that one before. I couldn't find anything that says you can pass strings to `opacity`, it has to be a number between zero and one.

Comment: what you want to as a output ?

Comment: @vaibs_cool thanks for your response, when i click a each div I want other div's are opacity,

Comment: It's better to write script additionally linked to jsFiddle.

Comment: what do you want ,when you move to other div, what does it mean?

Comment: @rishi click on other div

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/srsathish/b51smg3z/1/ check this , is this what you want?

Comment: Html is invalid. Close off your `divs` with `</div>` rather than `/>`

Comment: This question is not clear what it's want. You'r code not working as any opinion correctly, clear but what you expect from code exactly! not clear. Please avoid writing questions in this way.

Comment: sorry QMater here after I reduce.,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are write no valid html code - see:

```
<div class="category-item" >
    <div class="img-responsive center-block">   </div>      
</div>
<div class="category-item" >
    <div class="img-responsive center-block">   </div>          
</div>
<div class="category-item" >
    <div class="img-responsive center-block">   </div>      
</div>
<div class="category-item" >
    <div class="img-responsive center-block">   </div>  
</div>
```

And js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".category-item").click(function(){
        $(".category-item").addClass("blue");
        $(this).addClass("black").removeClass("blue");
    });


});
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b51smg3z/4/)

Answer (score 1):

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b51smg3z/2/)
Try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".category-item").click(function(){
              $(".category-item.black").removeClass("black");
            $(this).addClass("black");
           $(".category-item").addClass("blue");

          });
        });
```

Comment: @vaibas what I expected, that was given by vladimir Bredihin

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krishna1989/rvwqx0b7/) try this code once

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".category-item").click(function(){
              $(".category-item").removeClass("blue");
              $(".category-item").removeClass("black");
     $(".category-item").addClass("blue");
                   $(this).addClass("black");
    });
    

  });
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/krishna1989/rvwqx0b7/) try this code once

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".category-item").click(function(){
              $(".category-item").removeClass("blue");
              $(".category-item").removeClass("black");
           $(".category-item").addClass("blue");
                        $(this).addClass("black");
          });


        });
```